# How to automatically adjust to fit all the text in hover text description image in WP

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

i have an image with a hover of its content from wordpress post. Can anyone help me how to make the text fit inside the hover effect of my image box. I am very confused why it doesnt fit. I am using a wordpress CMS. Please check my code below specially my css. Also i provided a screenshot where it behaves wrong. I will no longer post my javascript because there are no issue about it. Please focus in my css i think.. ? thanks.

[image: Image Screenshot]

Here is my CSS:

```
.top-featured-image {
    position:relative;
    width: 280px;
    overflow:hidden;
    display:inline;
}
.top-featured-image span {
    background-color: rgba(130,127,122,0.7);
    color:white;
    font-size: small;
    position:absolute;
    bottom: -97px;
    left:0px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    max-height: 100px;
    width:300px;
    display: none;
    float:left;
    text-align:left !important;
}
.top-featured-image span a {
    color:white;
}
.top-featured-image span a:hover {
    color:white;
}
.top-featured-image ul {
    list-style:none;
    display: inline;
}
```

Here is my HTML with wordpress post loop and i think there is no problem here ?. only CSS:
if

```
( $productsBlog->have_posts() ) : 
                ?>
<div class="container">
<ul class="image">
<div class="row row-centered">
    <?php while ( $productsBlog->have_posts() ) : $productsBlog->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-box1" onMouseOver="show_title<?php echo $count ?>()" onMouseOut="hide_title<?php echo $count ?>()">
        <li class="top-featured-image">
        <span class="effect" id="hoverli<?php echo $count ?>"><?php the_content( sprintf('<a href="%s">', esc_url(get_permalink())),'</a>'); ?></span>
        <?php the_post_thumbnail('productsize'); ?>

        </div>
        <?php if($count==2) :
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div class="row row-centered">';
        endif; ?>
        </li>
        <?php $count++; endwhile; ?>
        </ul>
        </div>


    <?php endif; 
    wp_reset_postdata();
```

Answer (score 0):

i need to try in the editor, but cloud be you use `max-height: 100px;`

I feel a bit confuse your css. But i need to try for be sure about don't work.
Anyway i today was working with this http://jsfiddle.net/51csqs0b/ I think you can take some inspiration.

Comment: thank you for your answer sir but still it doesn't. the width of the text overlapse sir. In your jsfiddle also sir. http://jsfiddle.net/51csqs0b/641/